# snoop wpf virus total

Tags: wpf, security, snoop

I would like to use [Snoop WPF](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to help in developing and troubleshooting my applications' UI.  The problem is, when I check the file on Virus Total, it says that it is infected, so I am not allowed to install it at work.  Has else had problems with this download?  Please see the report from Virus Total:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/piT27.jpg

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried building Snoop from source to see if the created binaries still show the presence of viruses?

Comment: Yes, it says even the source download is infected.

Comment: You should send the files 'infected' (I think there is no such infection) to the AV companies: Dr.Web, ClamAV, etc and the page will be 'whitepaged' (Exists that word?)

Comment: Great idea, thank you!

Comment: If I remove the SnoopInstaller project then the only engine that indicates an infection on VirusTotal is DrWeb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the SnoopInstaller project and after that it passed my company's antivirus scan.  So now just build and run from source.

**UPDATE:**

Needed to install Visual Studio 2008 and sp1 because when you install this also installs all the required C++ redistributables.

Then I actually opened the Snoop.sln file in Visual Studio 2015, changed all of the ManagedInjectorLauncher project to .NET Framework 4.5.2, and started debugging Snoop.